# CGMiner no output (LTC GPU mining)

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin, gpu, cgminer

Here is my run command:

```
cgminer -o stratum+tcp://coinotron.com:3334 -u user -p pass --scrypt
```

the only output in my terminal I get is (and only this):

```
[2013-11-30 11:34:02] Started cgminer 3.7.2
```

if <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> it I finally get this output:

```
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Summary of runtime statistics:
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Started at [2013-11-30 11:34:03]
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Pool: stratum+tcp://coinotron.com:3334
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Runtime: 0 hrs : 0 mins : 40 secs                     
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Average hashrate: 0.0 Kilohash/s                
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Solved blocks: 0                     
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Best share difficulty: 0                     
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Share submissions: 0                     
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Accepted shares: 0                     
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Rejected shares: 0                     
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Accepted difficulty shares: 0                   
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Rejected difficulty shares: 0                   
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Hardware errors: 0                     
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Utility (accepted shares / min): 0.00/min       
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Work Utility (diff1 shares solved / min): 0.00/min
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Stale submissions discarded due to new blocks: 0
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Unable to get work from server occasions: 0                 
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Work items generated locally: 1                 
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Submitting work remotely delay occasions: 0     
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] New blocks detected on network: 1
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] Summary of per device statistics:
[2013-11-30 11:34:43] GPU0     | (5s):0.000 (avg):0.000h/s | A:0 R:0 HW:0 WU:0.0/m
```

my GPU is properly detected:

```
11:34:56 me@ArchPC::~/Desktop cgminer -n
 [2013-11-30 11:36:35] CL Platform 0 vendor: NVIDIA Corporation                    
 [2013-11-30 11:36:35] CL Platform 0 name: NVIDIA CUDA                    
 [2013-11-30 11:36:35] CL Platform 0 version: OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 6.0.1                    
 [2013-11-30 11:36:35] Platform 0 devices: 1                    
 [2013-11-30 11:36:35]  0   GeForce 9600 GT                    
 [2013-11-30 11:36:35] 1 GPU devices max detected                    
 [2013-11-30 11:36:35] USB all: found 6 devices - listing known devices                    
 [2013-11-30 11:36:35] No known USB devices
```

What could the problem be?

EDIT: Just tried it without `--scrypt`... it works then, but I need scrypt for LTC. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently I do not have enough points yet to give your answer a vote, but your solution also worked for me! Adding -T to the command line command did the trick. Not only do I now get a neat output of what is happening; the -T parameter also made the entire mining process actually **work**!

**Before adding the -T command:**
Screen flashed with the "Started CGMiner 3.7.2" message.
No messages were shown until I pressed CTRL + C.
The report said that only one share had been submitted and accepted - *every time* I ran CGMiner.

**After adding the -T command:**
The screen doesn't flash any more. 
Everything that happens is outputted line by line to my command prompt.
CGMiner is actually *working and submitting shares*. As we speak I'm on a total of 3616 accepted difficulty shares, contrary to 32 before.

Comment: +1 - Fixed it for me. For those wondering, '-T' is a shortcut for '--text-only', used to disable ncurses formatted screen output.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your bat file has these two lines first

```
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
```

Answer (score 0):

-T flag fixed this for my laptop. Something with ncurses text formatting

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem as well, but hated running with the `-T` toggle on.
I found out that it had to do with the ncurses lib missing on my freshly installed Win7 system, so after I installed [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) cgminer worked without the `-T` toggle and with the normal stats screen.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the -T workaround, I found the fix for my machine was to delete the `.bin` file generated. The fault was reproducible every single time if I left it alone.

Since I execute from a batch file, I just added a line before executing cgminer:

```
del scrypt*.bin
```

Naturally, this deletes any `.bin` files prefixed with `scrypt` (leaving others alone if you're mining something else using the same base directory).

Answer (score 0):

Adding --no-restart to my command fixed this problem for my 290x setup